# How do i refresh a divs with oneClick on a image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, refresh

I have searched but i can't understand because no one explain.
So this is what i want to do: I want to refresh divs without reloading the whole page. Like this.:

```
 <div id="topimage">
 <span id="happysmile"><img alt="happysmile" src="happysmile.png"></a></span>
 <span id="refreshbuttn"><img alt="refreshbuttn" src="refreshbuttn.png"></a></span>
                </div>

<div id="topDatum"><script type="text/javascript">
var mynewdate = new Date();
document.write(mynewdate.getMilliseconds());
</script></div>
```

So i just want to reload the "sec" div not the topimage div. with just clicking the refreshbuttn.png.

Is this possible, and how do you do it?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What is the "sec" div? Do you mean the "topDatum" div?

Answer (score 1):

If by the "sec" div you mean the "topDatum" div, you can do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/YCM9m/1/

```
<div id="topimage">
    <span id="happysmile"><img alt="happysmile" src="happysmile.png"></span>
    <span id="refreshbuttn"><img alt="refreshbuttn" src="refreshbuttn.png"></span>
</div>

<div id="topDatum"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('refreshbuttn').onclick = function() {
        var mynewdate = new Date();
        document.getElementById('topDatum').innerHTML = mynewdate.getMilliseconds();
    }
</script>
```

This uses `document.getElementById` to get the element with the ID `refreshbuttn`. It gives it an `onclick` handler that creates a date object, and gets the element with the ID `topDatum` and sets its `innerHTML` to the value of `mynewdate.getMilliseconds()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you **are** using jQuery you could use the following:

```
$("#refreshbuttn").click(function(){
    var mynewdate = new Date();
    $("#topDatum").html(mynewdate.getMilliseconds());
});
```

It will, listen the the object with **ID** `refreshbuttn`  for clicks *(in this case the object is the refreshbuttn span)*.
When it is it will get a new date.
Then it will set the *HTML* of the object with the **ID** `topDatum` to the new milliseconds *(in this case the object is the topDatum DIV)*.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/EfhGd/)**

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get started: http://jsbin.com/iwebo4/edit. Here is the JavaScript part:

```
function updateMilliseconds() {
  if (document.getElementById('hello')) {
    document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML
      = new Date().getMilliseconds();
  }
}

updateMilliseconds();​
```